# Retrieve ASP.Net AutoGenerated MachineKey

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a .Net 1.1 app that must be upgraded to 2.0.  The application encrypts passwords in the database using MD5CryptoServiceProvider.  After I upgraded to 2.0, the MD5 value was different.  In the machine.config, the machinekey was set to autogenerate.

Is there a way to retrieve this key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider.aspx) doesn't rely on the ASP.NET `system.web/machineKey` settings. These are used to control tamper proofing and encryption of ViewState, forms authentication tickets, and role cookies ([How To: Configure MachineKey in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx)).

I just compiled a simple console application under .NET 1.1 and 2.0 that performs a MD5 hash and they both produce the same value. I ran these applications on two different machines (one with autogenerated machine keys, and one with hard coded keys), again, identical results.

This sounds like the Encoding used is possibly different, i.e. the 1.1 application is using `ASCIIEncoding` and the 2.0 application is using `Unicode`.

Another thing to check is if the method you're using a uses salt that you've forgotten about, that would certainly cause different hashes to be generated.

Comment: You're exactly right.  The ASCIIEncoding class was implemented differently in 2.0 than 1.1.

Comment: @Jared - yay!...you know you can upvote a correct answer as well if you really like it :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can with a bit of reflection, [see here for details and code](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/how_to_read_auto_generated_machinekey.aspx) :)

Though, I'm not sure that `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` actually uses the machine key, I thought it was independent, someone correctly me in comments?

Comment: when i convert the virtual directory to 2.0, the encryption breaks.  is there anyway to get this without code?

Comment: @Jared - Not that I'm aware of, but any .Net application on the machine can run the code, a small console app for example would work to display the key.

Comment: @Jared - Way to break the comment box width!  Can you post example code that has the result changing, AFAIK MD5 doesn't depend on any key, it's a standardized hash: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5  But...I'm not all that familiar with the Crypto providers in .Net (not much use to me as of yet), so maybe it's some variant that's not actually just an MD5 hash.

Comment: sorry about that.

here's the code. like i said before, it's a 1.1 application upgraded to 2.0.  

            var encryptionServiceProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

            var bytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputString);

            var passwordHash = encryptionServiceProvider.ComputeHash(bytes);