# Hashing and keys on webfarms with MD5CryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net, md5, hash

Does the hashing algorithm of the [MD5CryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider.aspx) use some sort of key? If I have a webfarm (or multiple web roles in Windows Azure) will the result of a hash always be the same given the same input on different servers? Or do I have to set some sort of key on the web.config across all servers?

Comment: What do you want to use the hash for? And what do you hash? What security guarantees do you require?

Comment: We don't need for this to be incredibly secured. We're passing in some parameters to a URL using the querystring and we just need minor security to make sure the parameters weren't tampered with.

Comment: In that case HMAC is likely the correct solution. Don't construct an ad-hoc MAC from a hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cryptographic hash functions will always give the same result. They don't take a key.

But I would avoid MD5 in favor of SHA-2 for most applications. MD5 has been broken, in particular finding collisions is easy. And neither MD5 nor plain SHA-2 is fit for password hashing, if that's what you're doing.

There is a related concept: Message-Authentication-Codes (MAC). One of the most popular forms, HMAC is based on hashing the message and the key in a certain way.

---

To prevent tampering with parameters, I recommend using HMAC-SHA-256, with Base64 encoding. You can truncate it if it's too long. What you should NOT DO is using `Hash(key + message)`, that's trivially vulnerable to a length extension attack.

Answer (score 0):

According to this, [Retrieve ASP.Net AutoGenerated MachineKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2495120/retrieve-asp-net-autogenerated-machinekey) , the answer sounds like no (keys are not needed and things will work fine on a webfarm)